# How can I get the edge in Winston 1v1 fights?

Tags: overwatch

For 1v1 mode, how can I get the edge in a Winston fight? It feels like whoever clicks their mouse a millisecond sooner to start attacking tends to win by about 10 health. What can I do to build more of an edge in to help guarantee a win?

Just to be clear, I'm asking specifically about 1v1 mode, not about fighting another Winston in a 6v6 match.

Comment: Remember that Winston's jump/landing does damage too.

Comment: Yeah, we both seem to leap around like morons but never stick the landing. Tips for actually being successful at that might be key. :P

Comment: The landing hurtbox is pretty large as far as I can remember, almost like a Pharah rocket splash. You do have quite a degree of control over your flight path too, at least if you jump high enough. Small leaps directly at your opponent will help too, you don't necessarily need to go straight up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's get the obvious out of the way first: your shield offers no protection from another Winston.

Winston has 400 health and 100 armor. The 100 armor will effectively halve the damage taken from the Tesla Cannon, but thankfully there are ways to burn through it more quickly than tickling with electricity: Winston's Jump Pack deals 50 damage when landing close to an enemy, which is almost half of the enemy Winston's entire armor, and his melee attack deals 30 damage.

Since most of your damage will come from your Tesla Cannon, landing at least one jump while the enemy still has their armor will give you a significant advantage, so learn the minimum distance you can leap and bait enemies into that range before jumping on them and firing your main weapon. If the enemy has little armor remaining, a swift punch before continuing to fire your Tesla Cannon is also effective.

The cooldown on the Jump Pack is almost exactly the time it takes to empty a Tesla Cannon reload if firing continuously: try to reload right before jumping, so you don't awkwardly stand around the enemy Winston while waiting for your weapon to reload and make yourself even easier to track.

Many Winston players will jump straight up and try to land on you, the best way to counter this is to jump half a second after they do and follow them on the way down, avoiding damage and stomping them instead. On the flip side, don't try to do this to the enemy, instead go for short hops that are hard to avoid.

Lastly, don't forget that if the enemy has 30 HP or less, a melee attack is faster at killing them than your Tesla Cannon. In a close match, this can be the difference between winning and losing.

Comment: Winston's melee only does 40 damage while he's ulting - it's normally 30, like most other characters.

Comment: Would it be more beneficial to melee Winston until his Armor is gone, and then use the Tesla Cannon? Is the DPS on armor greater when melee-ing or from his Tesla Cannon?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf The DPS is exactly the same, but missing a punch will hurt you greatly. The benefit to punching is removing the last 25 armor without wasting Tesla Cannon ammo, so you don't have to reload 50 HP worth of ammo to deal 25 damage. Also keep in mind if you have to aim your punch at all, your Tesla Cannon comes out on top again.

Comment: Apparently you can also cancel you quick melee, by using it right before a landing. So if you jump on someone, punch him right before you land and get some bonus damage.